# Bind ToolTip.Content to a ProgressBar.Value in a DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, progress-bar, tooltip

Tried many ways like defining the binding as RelativeSource=TemplatedParent, RelativeSource=FindAncestor, TemplateBinding and even ControlTemplate but the ToolTip remains blank.

Note: not looking for a direct binding to a Path property since the template will feature many progress bars.

```
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type echoNestModel:dboAudioSummary}">
        <DataTemplate.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ProgressBar" >
                <Setter Property="Maximum" Value="1" />
                <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ToolTip>
                            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding RangeBase.Value}" />
                        </ToolTip>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </DataTemplate.Resources>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Read the documentation, TemplateBinding and TemplatedParent are for ControlTemplates only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
<Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
```

Comment: That's exactly what I just found using Blend, should have tried before asking ... thank you !